# Django does not display model data

Tags: python, django, upload, models

I have a few uploaded files and I want to display their names in a template. That technically shouldn't be a problem, that should work with

```
{% for obj in objs %}
<li>{{obj.field}}</li>
```

But in my case strangely it doesn't show anything. My files are uploaded and present in my database, but nothing shows. I have searched for a solution, but most similar problems had something to do with syntax mostly.

My Document class:

```
class Document(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.document)
```

And this is how I display them:

```html
<div class="card-body text-light">
            {% for file in doc %}
            <b>{{file.description}}</b>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
```

I have looked in the documentation and a couple more tutorials and in theory it should be able to display the files.

EDIT:

```
def user_panel(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'main/user_panel.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'main/login.html')
```

Comment: Can you show your view, which prepares data for template.

Comment: You mean the view which uploades the files or the view that renders the page in which I show all types of data including this specific one?

Comment: View that renders the page

Comment: I posted the view

Answer (score 1):

Your view is incorrect. `objs` queryset should be defined in context for `render` function. For example:

```
def user_panel(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = {'objs': Document.objects.all()}
        return render(request, 'main/user_panel.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/login.html')
```

Here is more on `render` function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: I see, but unfortunately I still don't get anything to show.

Comment: @CatalinC Could you publish your `settings.py`(without secret info), full definition of model, view, route and template on https://gist.github.com/ ? I would try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'll try to upload them

Comment: @CatalinC Just from a quick look. In `user_panel` view your context has variable `objs` but in template, you're referencing `docs`. Try to fix that, is it helped?

Comment: Ehm, I guess there is a misunderstanding. What I used there was the general idea on how the model data display could be done and should generally work, but mine didn't. In my case, I use docs, and technically should work, but somehow it doesn't, that was my initial reason for posting this thread

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding, instead of 'objs' in my view I put docs and that's all fine. Thank you for your help